# Content box below 960px - out of window

Tags: css

My content box (white box) with reduced width under 960px the text goes out of the window on the right side. I tried to figure out using inspector but seems to me like everything is defined as it should be.
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

HTML and CSS together:

https://codepen.io/drol/pen/RmLaZN

```css
#slika {
  height:70vh;
  width:100vw;
  background-color:#df1f26;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.imagetop {
  height:auto;
  width:100vw;
  float: left;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#crveni {
  position:relative;
  height:auto;
  width:100vw;
  background-color:#df1f26;
  padding-bottom:80px;
}

#sadrzaj {
  position:relative;
  top:-80px;
  left:20vw;
  width:510px;
  padding:35px;
  background-color:white;
  line-height:180% !important;

}

@media (max-width:960px) {
  h1 {
    color:#df1f26;
  }
  #sadrzaj {
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    width:100vw;
  }
  #crveni {
    padding-bottom:0px;
    position: absolute;
  }
  #slika {
  height:auto;
  }
  .imagetop {
  height:auto;
  width:100vw;
  object-fit: cover;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="slika"><img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/FUE7XiFApEqWZQ85wYcAfM-970-80.jpg" alt="" class="imagetop"></div>
<div id="crveni"><div id="sadrzaj"><h1>Main title</h1><h3>Subtitle of this post. Subtitle of this post. Subtitle of this post. Subtitle of this post. </h3><br/><p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus convallis nulla in ornare porttitor. Nam molestie dolor euismod commodo laoreet. Nam malesuada orci ac volutpat pretium. Nam lectus ante, facilisis ac urna eget, cursus semper nisl. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tellus orci, rutrum id auctor vel, convallis et lacus. Vestibulum luctus tincidunt purus pretium cursus. Vestibulum justo erat.</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `border-box` property is not defined in your CSS.

So, the content overflows the `body` due to `width: 100vw` AND the `padding: 35px;` are calculated as total width.

```
#sadrzaj {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100vw;
    box-sizing: border-box; //added box-sizing
}
```

[Solved JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/rfwbj93m/1/)

[Read more about box-sizing](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You define 100vw for #crveni and then for #sadrzaj again in the mediaquery. Together they make up for more than 100vw since they are inside each other. Just remove 100vw from the inner container and it should look good.

A small note: You shouldn't need to specify 100vw often, that's the default behaviour of elements.